# Sample audio from microphone to array of integers (C++/Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, audio, sampling

I am developing an app that records audio from microphone to integer array. Array is then passed to FFT and MFCC. I need to make frames about n samples and I need to 50% overlaps them (they cannot be side by side). So I need 3 buffers - when the first is full is passed to FFT. I this moment app should record second half of second buffer and first half of third buffer. FFT will be separate thread (my idea).

So I tried to sample audio using `QAudioRecorder` and `QAudioProbe`. I connected `audioBufferProbed` signal with `processBuffer` and there i use `buffer.constData<int>()`. I seems it works. I understood `audioBufferProbed` is emitted when buffer is full.

I don't know how to associate more buffers with one recorder. Or start writing to second buffer too at half of first buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way here (since 50% is a nice round number) is to ask Qt for frames **half** the size of the ones you need for your FFT. You now run your FFT over frames 0&1, 1&2, 2&3, etc.